# If two tags in the middle i need comma

Tags: functions, tags

```
<?php
                // Get the assigned tag_id
                $tag_ids = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

                // Check if there is any tag_ids, if print wp_tag_cloud
                if ( $tag_ids ) {

                    wp_tag_cloud( array(
                        'unit'     => 'px',       // font sizing choice (pt, em, px, etc)
                        'include'  => $tag_ids,   // ID's of tags to include, displays none except these
                    ) );
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`wp_tag_cloud()` accepts a `separator` parameter, so you can modify your call like this:

```
wp_tag_cloud( array(
    'separator' => ", ",       // Default value: "\n"
    'unit'      => 'px',       // font sizing choice (pt, em, px, etc)
    'include'   => $tag_ids,   // ID's of tags to include, displays none except these
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're outside the loop, use [`get_the_tag_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tag_list/).

```
get_the_tag_list( '', ', ', '', $post->ID );
```

Or if you're inside the loop just use [`the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_tags/):

```
the_tags();
```